# Can I do multiple actions to one component in a more elegant way?

Tags: java

I noticed the generated code in my Android project use the following technique to apply multiple actions to the Snackbar:

```
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Send message", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
     });
```

This does not seem to work on a regular java-swing project:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
       ((JButton) toolBar.getComponent(i)).setText(null)
                                          .setIcon(new ImageIcon(iconPath[i]));
```

which generates the following compile error:

```
    error: void cannot be dereferenced
      .setIcon(new ImageIcon(iconPath[i]));}
      ^
```

My solution is to simply do the following:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
        ((JButton) toolBar.getComponent(i)).setText(null);
        ((JButton) toolBar.getComponent(i)).setIcon(new ImageIcon(iconPath[i]));
    }
```

**My question is: Am I missing something or does it only work in Android projects and in that case, why?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not about Android or not. It's about the method's return type. The technique used by Snackbar in your example is called [Method Chaining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining#Java).

So it's a design decision made by others who implemented the classes you're using. It's not a language feature or something like that.

Comment: Okay, so since I am using JButton class I cannot use method chaining and will have to rely on the solution I posted above?

Comment: Short and easy: Yes. :)